# What paradigm shifts in thinking should a Rails or server-side developer make when beginning Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ember.js

While most of my recent work has primarily been with Ruby on Rails and a liberal dose of Javascript (mainly jQuery), I would like to build a single page application and realize that Ember.js seems to be an up-and-coming popular framework for approaching such apps.

From various sources of documentation and tutorials, it seems that Ember.js requires a very different way of thinking about how to solve problems than Ruby on Rails or other typical server-side frameworks. It seems possible that certain assumptions about 'the way things should work' that one develops over time using a framework such as Ruby on Rails may even get in the way of truly understanding and embracing the 'Ember Way.'

What preconceived notions should a Ruby on Rails developer need to eliminate when trying to learn Ember? And what are the most innovative and important Ember concepts that a Ruby on Rails developer should try to wrap his/her mind around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I think this is an awesome question, I believe it's more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What @ChristopherMarshall says is true. But I also upvoted and bookmarked the question since I'm interested in the answer :) and stackoverflow is by far the most active of all the stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to do my best to answer this question within the spirit of StackOverflow by listing some major technical differences between Ember and Rails. I'll leave the more philosophical side for somebody else over at [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

You can find all the code examples below in a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekidd/qNc3Q/) if that helps you visualize how everything fits together.

#### Separate routes for collections and objects

One major difference between Ember and Rails is the relation between collection routes (which manage a list of objects) and item routes (which manage a single object). In Rails, these are both handled by a single resource controller. In Ember, these are generally handled by two separate routes, because they manipulate two different data structures:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route("posts", { path: "posts" });
  this.route("post", { path: "post/:post_id" });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return App.Post.find();  
  }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return App.Post.find(params.post_id);  
  }
});
```

#### Routes vs. Controllers vs. Views vs. Templates

In Rails, your code is split between three major groups of classes:

- Models: An object-oriented abstraction over a database row.
- Views: Templates that can be rendered by a controller.
- Controllers: Accept HTTP requests, load and manipulate models, render views.

In Ember, the breakdown of responsibilities is considerably different.

**Models.** Ember models work much like Rails models.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  body: DS.attr("string"),
  comments: DS.hasMany("App.Comment")
});
```

**Routes.** Routes represent user-visible locations within your app, and they correspond to URLs like `/post/7` or `/about`. As you can see in the code examples above, routes do a lot more in Ember. Most importantly, they look up the models corresponding to a given URL. They're also in charge of hooking up appropriate controllers and views, as you'll see in a second.

**Controllers.** Controllers are nothing like Rails! The two most important things to understand about Ember controllers are that: (1) they're basically smart proxies around model objects, and (2) they're normally singletons. So you'll only have one `PostController` which will be wired up to whichever post you're looking at right now.

Generally speaking, you use Ember controllers to manage transient state that doesn't belong in the URL or in the database. Here's an example:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // This shared between all posts for as long as the app runs (because
  // this controller is a singleton), but it doesn't get saved in the database
  // (because this is a controller, not a model).
  lowRatedCommentsShown: false,

  // Called by PostView or its template in response to an HTML event.
  showLowRatedComments: function () {
    this.set("lowRatedCommentsShown", true);
  },

  // Called by PostView or its template in response to an HTML event.
  hideLowRatedComments: function () {
    this.set("lowRatedCommentsShown", false);
  } 
});
```

Because Ember controllers are proxies around models, they also tend to accumulate logic that *almost* belongs in the model, but feels too closely tied to a specific screen in your app.

**Views and templates.** Ember views and templates work together. It's best to think of them as a GUI widget.

```
App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({
  // This can be omitted when we're created by a route.
  templateName: 'post'

  // Any HTML event handlers would go here if we needed them.  Our job is to
  // map between HTML events and events understood by the controller.
  //doubleClick: function (evt) {
  //  // We'll actually bind this to a specific button, not a click event.
  //  this.get("controller").send("showLowRatedComments");
  //}
});
```

Our post template freely mixes fields defined by the model and fields defined by the controller:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>

  <div class="body">{{body}}</div>

  {{#if lowRatedCommentsShown}}
    <button {{action 'hideLowRatedComments'}}>Hide Low-Rated Comments</button>
  {{else}}
    <button {{action 'showLowRatedComments'}}>Show Low-Rated Comments</button>
  {{/if}}

  {{partial "comments"}}
</script>
```

Note that as fields on our model or controller change, the view will automatically rerender just those portions of the HTML which need to be updated!

#### Asynchronous behavior, computed properties, and bindings

Because Ember.js runs in the browser, many operations are asynchronous. Much of Ember's fundamental design is based on making asynchronous updates pleasant and easy. One key piece consequence of this situation is that objects load asynchronously. When you call `find`, you'll get back an unloaded object:

```
post = App.Post.find(params.post_id)
post.get("isLoaded"); // -> false
post.get("title");    // -> not yet available
```

When the server sends you the data, you'll see:

```
post.get("isLoaded"); // -> true
post.get("title");    // -> "Post #1"
```

To help make this painless, Ember relies heavily on [computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/), [observers](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/) and [bindings](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/). In each of these cases, the key idea is that changes to data should automatically ripple through the system. For example, we can use a computed property to ensure that `isLowRated` is updated any time that a comment's `rating` changes:

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo("App.Post"),
  body: DS.attr("string"),
  rating: DS.attr("number"),

  isLowRated: function () {
    return this.get("rating") < 2;
  }.property("rating") // A list of properties we depend on.
});
```

Note that Ember's Handlebars templates are deeply integrated with this system. When you write `{{title}}` in a template, you establish a binding that will automatically update the DOM whenever `title` changes. In the case of edit fields, this binding works in both directions! Changes to a displayed value will be pushed straight back to the model (though transactions may be used to roll it back).

It's also worth remembering that many of the dynamic updates—particularly bindings—run asynchronously at the end of the current "run loop". This is why you'll often see calls to `Ember.run` in test suites:

```
Ember.run(function () {
  // Change some bindings here. Not all changes will propagate immediately.
});
// Test that the values have all propagated here, after the run loop is done.
```

In practice, Ember feels much more asynchronous than Rails, but less asynchronous than an evented system like Node.js. This is because most asynchronous updates are managed automatically by bindings.

#### Surviving Ember Data

This is the one place I'm going to stray from strictly technical details and mention some practical advice. Ember Data provides `DS.Model`, seen above. It's not the only model layer for Ember.js—check out [ember-rest](https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest), [ember-resource](https://github.com/staugaard/ember-resource) and similar libraries for alternatives. At this point in time, there's no official release of Ember Data, but it can be used *very cautiously* in production apps if you like to live on the bleeding edge. Some tips:

1. Several major weak spots include validations, lazy loading and multiple open transactions. Before committing to Ember Data, write several small test programs to make sure it can actually do what you need it to do.
2. Don't pick fights with RESTAdapter. Feed it exactly [the JSON it wants](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/), even if that means building a proxy. In particular, this currently means serializing a complete list of IDs for every `hasMany` relationship in Rails when serializing an object. See [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) if you're using Rails.
3. Don't get too fixated on a specific design. Instead, be prepared to occasionally work around limitations and make compromises.

It's possible to get very good results with Ember Data. But it's vastly less mature than ActiveModel, and it needs to be treated as such.

Comment: +1 for your excellent and detailed response. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! One more thought about Ember controllers: They actually have a lot in common with the way some people use "presenters" in Rails, as a context-specific wrapper around a model that adapts it work well in a particular context.